# How to show Code Folding in Android studio

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How do you show this in Android studio?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android studio, go to File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Code Folding. Check "Show code folding outline":

[image: Enable code folding outline]